# redirecting logged in users to index if they try to access /login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm after a simple solution which I can't seem to work out. New to rails, so trying to learn and get the basics down.

When users aren't logged in and they try and access various pages, they are redirected to /login. What I want is to stop them form being able to view the /signin page IF they are already logged in.

How can I achieve this?

**Update**

**application_controller**

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end
```

**sessions_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

layout "empty"

def create
 user = User.find_by_user_name(params[:user_name])
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
  if params[:remember_me]
      cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    else
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    end
  flash[:success] = "You are now logged in"
  redirect_to '/'
else
    flash[:error] = "Invalid username or password"
  redirect_to '/login'
 end
end

def destroy
 cookies.delete(:auth_token)
 flash[:error] = "You have successfully logged out"
 redirect_to '/login'
end

private

end
```

Comment: What authentication system do you use?

Comment: It's a custom one following basic guide such as railscast. So the basic user controller with a session controller for an auth token.

Answer (score 3):

Add `before_action` for the action `/login` view, if you have `current_user` than you can do it like this

```
before_action :check_session, only: [:login]

def login
  # login page action
end

private

def check_session
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user.blank?
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I've updated my original comment to include the sessions_controller code. My current_user sits in my 'application_controller', so it might be a bit different. Tried a few different combinations and still can't get it to work.

Comment: I've resolved the issue now, I had the wrong name in the [:login] part. Thanks again!!